# How to deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I have a json:

```
{
  "clientId": "1",
  "appName": "My Application",
  "body": "Message body",
  "title": "Title"
  "data": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

And a DTO:

```
@Data
public class PushNotificationDto {
  private Long clientId;
  private String appName;
  private String body;
  private String title;
  private String data;
}
```

I'm using SpringBoot and my @RestController looks like this:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PushNotificationController {

  private PushNotificationService pushNotificationService;

  @PostMapping("/push-notification")
  void sendPushNotification(@RequestBody PushNotificationDto pushNotification) {
    pushNotificationService.send(pushNotification);
  }
}
```

Since data field in json object is actually an object but in my DTO it is a String, I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: 
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
```

What can I do so that such deserialization performs successfully?

Comment: You could change your `data` field type to `Object`, which will ultimately de-serialize it as a `LinkedHashMap`. The best practice would probably consist in having an actual POJO you can de-serialize it with though, and handle `String` conversion aside from de-serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your request object you have an array of `data`.

```
"data": {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

But in your `PushNotificationDto` object you have `String data`. That's the reason you're getting this error. To solve this error you can change `String data` to `Map<String,String>`

Answer (score 0):

This can also be a deployment issue. If you deployed the pojo after making changes, the service using this pojo is still using old class files, then there will be issue. If this is you. Then first deploy the pojo, then deploy all the services that are using it. This is what happened with me.